# self.registration.getNotifications() returns an empty array within the firebase-messaging-sw

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am using the Firebase Cloud Messaging service to push notifications to my web app. I send a push with data from server and catch it in the default firebase service worker in the setBackgroundMessageHandler function. I want to check if I can replace any existing notifications with new options, before returning the received payload as notification. Everytime I try to get the existing notifications using the self.registration.getNotifications() (with or without the optional tag object as parameter), I get an empty array returned, even if there are existing notifications. Why is this happening? Here is my firebase code in the service worker:

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
    var title = payload.data.title
    var options = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: './icons/512x512.png',
        badge: './icons/96x96.png',
        data: {
            module: payload.data.module
        },
        tag: payload.data.tag,
        renotify: true,
    }
    var replacementPromise
    //-- Check for replacement ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (payload.data.tag === 'new-message') {
        replacementPromise = new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
            self.registration.getNotifications({tag: payload.data.tag})
                .then(notifications => {
                    console.log(`got existing ${payload.data.tag} notifs`, notifications) //always as empty Array
                    if (notifications.length > 0) { //Never executes
                        const existingNotification = notifications[0]
                        const newMessagesCount = existingNotification.data.newMessagesCount + 1
                        const fromGrievances = existingNotification.data.fromGrievances
                        if (!fromGrievances.includes(payload.data.gid))
                            fromGrievances.push(payload.data.gid)
                        options.body = `You have ${newMessagesCount} new messages from ${fromGrievances.length} grievances.`;
                        options.data.newGrievanceCount = newGrievanceCount
                        title = `New Messages in Grievances`;
                        // Close the old notification
                        existingNotification.close();
                    } else { //Always executed as Array is of length 0
                        options.data.newMessagesCount = 1
                        options.data.fromGrievances = [payload.data.gid]
                    }
                    return true
                })
                .then(resolve)
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("Error getting existing notifications for replacement check: ", err)
                    resolve()
                })
        })
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if(replacementPromise) {
        replacementPromise.then(() => {
            console.log('Sending notif with', title, options)
            return self.registration.showNotification(title, options)   
        })
    }
    else return self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
})
```

The new notification, having the same tag as that of the existing notification, actually replaces the existing notification when returned. Yet, I can't get the existing notification through getNotifications().

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you please post some of the relevant code?

Comment: @OneLunchMan Edited to add the relevant code. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/common-notification-patterns#merging_notifications